# Using rails with phonegap

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, xcode, heroku, cordova

I have a fully functional rails app but, I want to create a mobile version using Phonegap. I've got Phonegap and Xcode set up but, I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

I want the mobile version to pull from the same database as the web version.

What technology can I use to achieve this?

Thanks,

Ramario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably expose your database through a REST API abstraction layer either with Rails or a separate application using something like Sinatra, which I personally find better suited to API development.

Then your mobile app can make REST calls to allow users to manipulate data from the same database.

Or you can of course just make your existing web UI mobile-friendly and have people just as easily work with your Rails app through the browsers in their phones as they do the browsers on their laptops.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into creating a REST API and use something like jQuery mobile for the front-end